# interface does not give me initalize method

Tags: annotations

I am missing method from interface

value of annotiations is null.
Already tried hardcoded, it works, but I need to be customizable.

package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc.validation;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CourseCodeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator {

```
private String coursePrefix;

public void initalize(CourseCode theCourseCode) {
    coursePrefix = theCourseCode.value();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String theCode, ConstraintValidatorContext theConstraintValidatorContext) {
    /*if (coursePrefix==null)
        coursePrefix = "LUV";*/
    System.out.println(theConstraintValidatorContext.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate());
    boolean result;

    if (theCode!=null) {
        System.out.println(coursePrefix);
        result = theCode.startsWith(coursePrefix);
    } else {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Expecting possible @Override method initialize

Answer (score 0):

initalize => initialize

just one letter missing